# Why is my load tester reporting 99% "connection reset by peer" errors when testing against my dummy server?

Tags: java, networking

I'm trying to set up a framework to let me experiment with the new Project Loom virtual threads. As part of that, I wrote a very very basic web server with the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000)) {
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                Thread.ofVirtual().start(() -> {
                    try {
                        handleRequest(clientSocket);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private static void handleRequest(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("");
        out.println("<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>");
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

I used [Locust](https://locust.io/) to generate some load on it, using the following `locustfile.py`:

```
from locust import HttpUser, task


class HelloWorldUser(HttpUser):
    @task
    def hello_world(self):
        self.client.get("/")
```

When I point Locust at the running server, both running locally on my M1 MacBook Pro running macOS Moneterey (12.5.1), it generates about 1,000 RPS, but about 99% of those tests fail with, according to Locust, `ChunkedEncodingError(ProtocolError("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')))` -- in my most recent run, 16,636 requests got generated, and 16,490 of them failed, leaving 146 successes total in about 17 seconds (so fewer than 10 successes per second). Manually going to http://localhost:9000 gives me the page I expect.

A few things I've tried:

- Using the alternate `ServerSocket` constructor that takes a max queue length. I changed this from the default 50 to `new ServerSocket(9000, 2000)`; no effect.
- I ran `ulimit -n 2048` on the theory that I was getting throttled by file descriptors. Changing this setting didn't seem to have any effect.
- Switching from virtual threads to platform threads. I didn't really expect this to have an effect, and indeed it did not.
- Asking ChatGPT :-) It had no idea, though it sounded pretty confident.

Any ideas what could be going wrong? It seems very surprising that such a simple web server would top out at ~10 requests per second.

Comment: maybe your server is just not capable of serving the responses quick enough? Or you have a firewall active that blocks off too many subsequent requests, but it is not probable for localhost interface. Btw: did you try to target `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, so name resolution can be ruled out as source of problems?

Comment: Good thoughts, thanks. I tried 127.0.0.1; no effect. I've got the standard macos firewall enabled and I can't disable it, but I haven't found any reference suggesting that it might rate-limit connections.

Comment: Can you log the `clientSocket.getLocalPort()` to see if it's actually using different ports for the incoming connections or maybe reusing the same port over and over again?